# Remove widgets from titlebars in gnome

Tags: titlebar, widgets

Is there a way to remove the widgets from the title bars in gnome windows?

I am talking about these...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Basically any widget.

The only things I really want on my title bars are these..

[image]

Comment: Screens keep getting bigger and better, and yet we as a society keep stuffing more and more content into the top and bottom three inches of the screen. It baffles me sometimes. Excellent question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install `gtk3-nocsd` to achieve this.

```
sudo apt install gtk3-nocsd
```

Then restart your computer.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Image source: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ZaWertun/gtk3-nocsd)

Note that some apps may not look as good after installing `gtk3-nocsd`.

Comment: is there also a way to replace the widgets with a menu bar?

Comment: @Shadowblitz16 No, GNOME Devs removed that. The solution is to use MATE apps (Caja instead of Nautilus, Pluma instead of Gedit) or KDE apps, which did not get rid of good old menubars for the sake of "modern design". See this webpage for MATE apps. https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/#!pages/applications.md