# Is there a way to slim down ubuntu's titlebar widgets?

Tags: window, titlebar, window-buttons, widgets

Is there a way to reduce the size of the widgets on the window title bar's in ubuntu 20.04?

I recently decided [1348271](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348271/remove-widgets-from-titlebars-in-gnome/1348273?noredirect=1#comment2304741_1348273) didn't work for me and decided to do [821813](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821813/how-to-slim-down-ubuntu-gnome-title-bar-fatness).

But I would still like to shrink the size of them so they don't look so thick.

Is there a way to get these to look around the size of the minimize, maximize and close buttons?
[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276951/55205 Also, this GTK theme has smaller headerbars compared to many other themes. https://github.com/vinceliuice/Matcha-gtk-theme. BTW, installing Caja or Nemo instead of Nautilus may solve your issue. They don't have a headerbar.

Comment: nope the widgets on the title bar are still the same size, and that actually increased the size of the titlebar itself